# Call method in EJB on JBoss startup

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb, lifecycle

I'm looking for an entry point in an EJB deployed on JBoss.

Servlets have the  `load-on-startup`  tag to use in its `web.xml`.

I'm searching for similar `init()` functionality for an EJB.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That didn't exist for EJB until 3.1. With EJB 3.1 you can use a singleton bean to simulate that:

From [Application Startup / Shutdown Callbacks](http://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/application_startup_shutdown_callbacks):

```
   @Startup
   @Singleton
   public class FooBean {

       @PostConstruct 
       void atStartup() { ... }

       @PreDestroy
       void atShutdown() { ... }

   }
```

Otherwise, you will need to rely on the good old trick to use a `ServletContextInitializer`.

There are some application-specific extension, e.g. [lifecycle listener](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/docs/DG/beamc.html) for Glassfish. Maybe there's such a thing for JBoss.

But if I were you I would try to rely on standard features as much as possible. The problem with non-standard extension is that you never know exactly what can be done or not, e.g. can you start transaction or not, etc.

Comment: Alternatively one can always use a MBean with start/stop lifecycle methods. The MBean is injected with the EJB needed and calls whatever methods from it that are required.

Comment: Thanks.
Two great posts. I ended up with a "ServletWrapper" instead. But a refactor is on the agenda.
Cheers!

Comment: I am using jboss 5.1 (not sure if it supports EJB3.1) I can use this Technic to invoke method on deploy? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This article describes seven different ways of invoking functionality at server startup. Not all will work with JBoss though.

[Seven ways to get things started. Java EE Startup Classes with GlassFish and WebLogic](http://blog.eisele.net/2010/12/seven-ways-to-get-things-started-java.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you're targeting JBoss AS 5.1, and you don't mind using the [JBoss EJB 3.0 Extensions](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/reference/build/reference/en/html/jboss_extensions.html), you can build a service bean to bootstrap your EJB.  If your service implements an interface annotated with the `@Management` annotation and declares a method with the signature `public void start() throws Exception`, JBoss will call this method when it starts the service.  You can then call a dedicated `init()` method on the EJB you want to initialize:

```
@Service
public class BeanLauncher implements BeanLauncherManagement
{
    @EJB private SessionBeanLocal sessionBean;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception
    {
        sessionBean.init();
    }
}

@Management
public interface BeanLauncherManagement
{
    public void start() throws Exception;
}
```

More information on this, including additional life-cycle events, can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/reference/build/reference/en/html/jboss_extensions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Managed Beans can be used to do some process at JBoss startup, you have to add entry of that managed bean in configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the following line to the top of the method you want to run at startup:

```
@Observer("org.jboss.seam.postInitialization")
```