# EJB module initialization listener

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ejb, listeners

It's posible to define a listener for EJB 3.0 .jar that is called in the module/context initialization?
Similar to the ServerContextListener for web project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, not with EJB 3.0. With EJB 3.1 you can use a Singleton EJB to do so.

From [Application Startup / Shutdown Callbacks](http://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/application_startup_shutdown_callbacks):

```
   1:  @Startup
   2:  @Singleton
   3:  public class FooBean {
   4:   
   5:    @PostConstruct 
   6:    void atStartup() { ... }
   7:   
   8:    @PreDestroy
   9:    void atShutdown() { ... }
  10:   
  11:  }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995511/call-method-in-ejb-on-jboss-startup/2995593#2995593) for more details.