# @Startup not working in JBOSS 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi, java-ee-7

I want to force a singleton bean to be created eagerly when the container starts. I combined it with @PostContruct (for some initialization logic) and @PreDestroy (for some clean up). However whatever I tried it does not work in my JBOSS 7 EAP (which is JEE 7).

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
@Startup
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class ProvisioningDataForApplicationLifecycle {
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // when app is deployed
        LOG.info("called init")
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void cleanUp() {
        // when app is undeployed
        LOG.info("called destroy")
    }
}

public void someOtherClass(){
   @Inject
   @EJB
   private ProvisioningDataForApplicationLifecycle pdal;
   ...
}
```

I searched a lot [1](http://blog.eisele.net/2010/12/seven-ways-to-get-things-started-java.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995511/call-method-in-ejb-on-jboss-startup), [3](https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/cdi-and-startup/) ... but nothing helped. The only thing which I got working is using

`public void initEnvironment(@Observes @Initialized(@ApplicationScoped.class))`

However the @Startup should be working. So any idea why it is not?

**Update:**

I think I realized the problem: The class is part of an (eclipse) utility project (facet) which is added to the final EAR as a jar file under the `lib` folder. So it is not an an EJB. Thus the `@Startup` and `@Singleton` annotation will probably not work. Or is there the possibility to make it work for non EJB classes?

Comment: Is your `@Singleton` an EJB annotation? Because there is `@javax.ejb.Singleton` (this is what you want) and `@javax.inject.Singleton` (not what you want).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out however that was not the case...

Comment: that configuration should work. when you check logs of jboss when creating the ejb beans in jndi namespace, is the bean logged with its global, module and local lookupnames?

Comment: There are no such log entries which made me realize the class is not an EJB. See update of the post...